# Message ID not retained between remote and local queues

Tags: ibm-mq

When I MQPUT a message to a remote queue, I obtain the Message ID and log it.

When I open the MQ Browser to look at messages on the local queue on a different queue manager, I see the message with a different Message ID.

Is there a way to ensure that the Message ID assigned at the Remote Queue is retained at the Local Queue?

I am using `MQMI_NONE` and `MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID` option when doing the PUT operation.

I am using IBM Websphere MQ 7.5.0.4.

Comment: Using a remote queue definition does not change the message ID. There must be some component processing the message between you sending it and checking the message ID.

Comment: Btw. you don't need both MQMI_NONE and MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID, either one on its own is enough to make the queue manager generate a message ID.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to ensure that the Message ID assigned at the Remote Queue is retained at the Local Queue?

Two requirements:

1. Make sure that MQ is the thing moving the message.
2. Do not use pub/sub.

If you use IBM's MQ Pub/Sub implementation, they consider the message published to a topic and the one received by a subscriber to be completely different messages.  This, as far as I (and many others, including the JMS Specification lead) believe, breaks the JMS specification.  However it is the behavior we have for now so if you do not want the message ID to change then don't use IBM's Pub/Sub.

If MQ moves a point-to-point message from one QMgr to the next, the details of the message remain unchanged, unless a channel exit or other intermediary intercepts the message.  This is part of the base functionality of the product and you do not need to do anything special to make that happen.

If you are seeing some other behavior, it is most likely that something you are unaware of is intercepting and processing the messages.  Alternatively, the application code may not be capturing the `MQMD.MsgID` at the right time.  You can of course easily reconcile your expectations about the code and the message ID by taking an API trace.  The [MA0W SupportPac](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA0W) is designed to do just that and will show you the message fields both before and after the API call.

The only other possibility is an MQ bug.  A bug that affects message ID would be so fundamental that it would be extremely unlikely to get out and if it did it would be caught and fixed almost immediately, so it isn't probable that this is an MQ bug.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the Message ID is a binary field. If you are putting some text into the Message ID and saving it away, then IBM MQ moves the message to another platform the binary representation may be different characters on that platform. For example if you MQPUT the message on a Windows machine (ASCII) and then looked at again on a z/OS machine (EBCDIC) then the character representation would be very different.